# Extract ODE System from OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is it possible to extract the ODE System from OpenModelica?

Using the nice GUI of OpenModelica to generate an ODE System which can be solved for further processings for example in Python would be really nice!

I know about the FMI interface, which we use at the moment for our simulations, but due to many bugs and problems which occur especially by the usage of PyFMI, just using ODE system might give us more control and stability in our further research.